# Failed to use variable with LOAD DATA INFILE MYSQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following mysql code (LOAD DATA ) while uploading csv. I want to set the value of some field manually. But i can't do this.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
(schedule_code, p_year, adscode)
```

This code works. But I when I want to set values of adscode with a php variable or manually static value, it generates error. Here is my code that i have tried but failed:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.csv'
        INTO TABLE my_table
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES 
        (adscode)
        SET 
            adscode= $adscode
```

Can you please help me?